# Predicting the stability of coordination compounds using Crystal field theory

Tags: coordination-compounds

**The question is this**:

On the basis of CFT, predict with justification which of the following two complex ions would be more stable [Mn(CN)6]4- or [Fe(CN)6]4-.

**Attempt at solution**:

Both the complexes are low spin. Filling in the d electrons we get 5 electrons in t<sub>2g</sub> for Mn2+ and 6 electrons in t<sub>2g</sub> for Fe2+. There are no electrons in e<sub>g</sub> for both.

Mn2+ has one unpaired electron while Fe2+ has completely filled t<sub>2g</sub> level. From here I was in a dilemma because Fe has fully occupied t<sub>2g</sub> level as well as a higher charge density because the effective ionic size of Fe2+ in low spin is 61 pm while Mn2+ in low spin has size 67 pm. However, due to Jan Teller effect the Mn compound will gain more stability due to the unsymmetrical filling of the t<sub>2g</sub> level. I know that Jan Teller distortion for t<sub>2g</sub> is less pronounced, so I was wondering if it was enough to make the complex more stable than Fe2+ complex?

Comment: A simpler approach, somewhat ridiculous, I agree. But look : $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ is {Ar} + 6 electrons. If 6 $\ce{CN^-}$ are approaching, each one brings one doublet. The iron outer shell has now : 6 + 6·2 = 18 electrons. This is like the Krypton atom. Manganese ion cannot do this.

Comment: CFT is outdated and deprecated: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/131780/crystal-field-splitting-of-other-orbitals/131789#comment254617_131789

Comment: Horrible question as the word "stability" has little meaning unless you state with respect to what change you are considering some is stable or not. But I suspect https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Crystal_Field_Theory/Crystal_Field_Stabilization_Energy may help you give them the answer they want.

Comment: @Ian Bush I read that site and drew the above conclusions from there. I just want to know if they are correct. I think stability refers to the complex with the least energy.